# Can't create a file even if rights allow and I've relogged in

Tags: unix, filesystems

I try to create file in folder with group write access, user tomcat7 is in group. Why isn't it workin?

```
skr@konrad~/data/asu$ sudo -u tomcat7 sh
$ whoami
tomcat7
$ echo > /home/skr/data/asu/g.gz.index
sh: 2: cannot create /home/skr/data/asu/g.gz.index: Permission denied
$ ls -la /home/skr/data/asu/
total 18708
drwxrwxr-x  2 skr skr     4096 Sep 29 08:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 85 skr skr     4096 Jul 30 00:42 ..
$ grep ^skr /etc/group
skr:x:1002:tomcat7:mail
```

Tried to logout, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the output of `id` or `groups`. These commands show the truth of what groups the current process is actually a member of, more than grepping `/etc/group` does. You will probably find that the "tomcat7" user is not actually a member of the "skr" group as you intended it to be.

The reason is that you have a syntax error in `/etc/group`: each line of that file is supposed to contain 4 colon-delimited fields (group name, password, gid, list of members), but the line you show has 5 fields. Remove the extraneous field and delimiter (`:mail`) and try again.